# tidyverse spread with duplicate keys and fill NAs based on unique keys

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

Consider the minimal example:

```
library(tidyverse)
ex <-tribble(
  ~id, ~property, ~value,
  1,    "A",      9,
  1,    "A",      8,
  1,    "B",      7,
  2,    "A",      6,
  2,    "B",      5
)
```

My goal is to spread the property into columns to get this table:

```
tribble(
  ~id, ~A, ~B,
  1,  9,  7,
  1,  8,  7,
  2,  6,  5
)
```

Grouping by `id` and `property` and adding a key gets close but leaves NA:

```
## almost but not quite
ex %>% 
  group_by(id, property) %>%
  mutate(key = row_number()) %>%
  spread(property, value) %>% 
  select(-key) -> X
X
```

Gives:

```
     id     A     B
1     1     9     7
2     1     8    NA
3     2     6     5
```

I can solve this in the minimal example by splitting out the above by each `property`, dropping NAs, and joining back by `id`:

```
inner_join(
  na.omit(select(X, id, A)),
  na.omit(select(X, id, B))
)
```

but clearly that does not generalize to arbitrary set of properties.  What is a better `tidyverse` strategy to do this?

**NOTE:** Several previous questions speak to the first half of this, e.g. constructing the `key` column so that `spread` does not fail, but couldn't see something addressing the `NA`s.

Comment: You only have 2 values for B, but 3 for A, why do you expect it to not give you an `NA` for B? Are you just merely wanting to fill the NA with the previous value?

Comment: @useR because we know the property B for the object with id 1 based on the other rows for id 1.   Essentially property A is something that can be multi-valued (think paper with id 1 can have multiple 'keywords' (property A) where each appears in a separate row, bc I don't like list-values in the table.

Comment: Right, but why you do expect the _program_ to know that? When you only have one "B" in id1 but two "A"'s, the key generated when grouping by `id` and `property` would have `1` and `2` for the two values of "A" but only `1` for "B". This creates a missing value for B when spreading, since there was no `key==2` for "B".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fill` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ex %>% 
  group_by(id, property) %>%
  mutate(key = row_number()) %>%
  spread(property, value) %>% 
  select(-key) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(-id)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id     A     B
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     9     7
2     1     8     7
3     2     6     5
```

Comment: fill is nice, but it looks like it is based not on id but merely on the next or previous row.  That seems very fragile -- even sorting by id first, we cannot be sure that will always be a row with the same id.

Comment: @cboettig You can always `group_by(id)`. See my edit.

Comment: I guess it is actually already grouped by `id` in this case, good to know that fill respects the group